# how to get latest date and time in php and mysql using a select statement

Tags: php, datetime, mysql

how to get latest date and time in php and mysql using a select statement? is that possible
My field type is data time
it looks like this "2010-06-08 01:41:27" . any help is appreciated guys.

edit:
sorry not so clear with my question...(ugh!)
basically I have a column in my table which has a field of datetime (did I say it right, it has a data type of datetime?) ,  these are fill up already with some data , All I need to do is get the latest in that field, is there a need to compare it ?

Answer (score 3):

i think you are looking for this:
`select max(datetime_column) from table`

But your question isn't all that clear.

Comment: thanks man, I have updated the question , I will try your suggestion.

Comment: From what i can tell from your question this is exactly what you want. Say you have 2 records in your table, this query returns the record with the highest value in your datetime typed column.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, use this:

```
SELECT NOW();
```

to get the current date/time.  In PHP, use the `time()` function.

You can also insert the current time into a database field using this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`date`) VALUES (NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Select now()` 
this may help u

for getting any value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the record with the latest datetime column in it, do this:

```
select * from your_table order by your_datetime_column desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With your question, it shows that you really wanted to get the latest input from your database which has the present date and time. I think this should solve your problem

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(`date_and_time_column_name`)= CURDATE();
```

This will surely do the job.